# High time in External Clock drive

Tags: atmega328p, clock-speed, internal-resistance

While looking for the rise time and fall time of external clock in ATMega328p, I came across the term "High time". Is it same as "ON time" i.e. time taken to reach 10% of amplitude? I have attached snippet of the datasheet which I'm referring to
[image: ATMega328p external clock drive]

Also can someone help how much internal resistance is seen on the pin of the MCU? I'm using Arduino Uno here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details you need are defined in the waveform image right above the table you pasted.

Yes, High Time is same as "On Time" usually but your definition is way off. High Time is the time that signal spends above the logic threshold definition for high logic level. In this case, it must be higher than Vih1, which is either 0.8×Vcc or 0.7×Vcc, depending on supply voltage Vcc range.

The internal resistance will be approximately infinite so it is undefined. It is a CMOS logic level input. If you want to know capacitive loading or leakage current, they are defined in the electrical specs.